# Search function for the same class name

Tags: javascript

i have a function that i'm working with in javascript to highlight every other row of a given table that is named by the same class ...i am running into a problem, the code works great but it will only detect the first table named with that class...i need it to perform the task for every single table named with the same class.

i've tried a few things but nothing worked...any suggestions?
thanks!

heres what i'm working with

```
  function start(){
     var list=document.getElementsByClassName("highlight");
     for(i=0; i<list.length; i++){
     var element= list[i].getElementsByTagName("tr");

for(i=0; i<element.length; i++)
{
    if (i%2 == 0) {
        element[i].className = "odd"
    }
    else{
        element[i].className = "even";
    }
  }
    }
  }

   window.addEventListener("load", start, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a different variable in the inner for statement.

See a working sample here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wsCxG

```
window.onload = start;

function start(){
    var list=document.getElementsByClassName("highlight");

    for(i=0; i<list.length; i++)
     {
         var element= list[i].getElementsByTagName("tr");

        for(j=0; j<element.length; j++)
        {
            if (j%2 == 0) {
                element[j].className = "odd"
            }
            else{
                element[j].className = "even";
            }
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about pure css3?

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {
 background-color: green;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
 background-color: red;
}
```

with highlight

```
.highlight tr:nth-child(odd) {
 background-color: green;
}
.highlight tr:nth-child(even) {
 background-color: red;
}
```

example

http://jsfiddle.net/RppAT/

if you want js (shorthand+while--)

```
function OE(){
 var lists=document.getElementsByClassName("highlight"),listsLength=lists.length;
 while(listsLength--){
  var trs=lists[listsLength].getElementsByTagName("tr"),trsLength=trs.length;
  while(trsLength--){
   trs[trsLength].className=(trsLength%2==0)?'odd':'even';
  }
 }
}
window.onload=OE;
```